# Unable to execute chrome.tabs.XX functions in Shortcut Manager extension

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, plugins

I'm trying to assign a block of javascript in Shortcut Manager,

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  alert (tab.url);
});
```

When it's executed, it tells me chrome.tabs was undefined,

So I tried to execute it in the development panel:

[image]

What could be missing here ? An internal js library needs to be loaded ?

Chrome version: `Version 21.0.1180.89 (154005)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `chrome.tabs` can only be accessed inside extensions, so you wouldn't be able to access it from the dev tools or in your shortcut.

Comment: You mind checking this out:  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227296/chrome-tabs-getselected-is-undefined-on-latest-chrome-that-uses-manifest-version`, I got problems running it in a extension